# GWT DateBox validation

Tags: gwt

What is the best way to do a full date value validation using the DateBox widget?

The following just prevents incomplete input like "**1.1.**" but allows for example: "**333.333.333**"

```
final DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
dateBox.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(format));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
try {
    Date date = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_SHORT).parseStrict(value);
    // Do something with date
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // Show error message
}
```

You can use a different format, obviously, or you can try to parse all formats one by one if you allow your users a freedom to enter dates as `1/1/2013` as well as `Jan 1, 2013`, `January  1, 2013`, etc.

Comment: Thx!

I extended DateBox.DefaultFormat and overode the `parse()` method to use `parseStrict()`.